# SQL query for entries not spanning multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Say I have an oracle table that looks like this:

[image]

So, a sample can have 2 rows, one where `test_value == value1` and one where `test_value == value2`, or one of them can be missing.

If I want to query for all the samples that have a `value1` row but NOT a `value2` row (i.e., all samples with a missing `value2` row), how would I do that?

(I.e., in my example, I would expect to find sample2.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `not exists`:

```
select *
from t
where t.test_value = 'value1' and
      not exists(select 1 form t t2 where t2.sample = t.sample and t2.test_value = 'value2');
```

If you just want the *samples* and not the complete rows, then aggregation can also be used:

```
select sample
from t
where test_value in ('value_1', 'value_2')
group by sample
having min(test_value) = max(test_value) and
       max(test_value) = 'value1';
```

Actually, for your particular strings, that can be simplified to:

```
having max(test_value) = 'value1'
```

Comment: The `having` variant threw errors at me (ORA-00937: not a single-group group function), but the `not exists` solution works perfectly, thank you!

Comment: What role does the where-clause in the `having` query play? Is there a reason not to simply omit it?

Comment: @CodingCat . . . It is not needed if those are the only two values.  However, the question leaves open the possibility that there are more values.

Answer (score 0):

try this, it detects the cases of samples which has only 1 value, and then checks that this value is value1.

```
SELECT SAMPLE
FROM 
    (
    SELECT SAMPLE, SUM(CASE WHEN TEST_VALUE = 'value1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS IS_TEST_VALUE1
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY SAMPLE
    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    ) AS X
WHERE IS_TEST_VALUE1 = 1
```